# Automatic update of Inno Setup program

Tags: windows, winapi, inno-setup

Is there a way to make a running program update itself, via the Inno setup installer? Or is it necessary to [quit](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=technotes) the running program before it can be upgraded?

Comment: It's not necessary, but much better to quit your application before you overwrite its binary file.

Comment: @TLama, why is it better? Is it even possible to overwrite the binary file it the app has not quit? Since you are an Inno setup insider, I have really high hopes now! :)

Comment: 1. Because not always you'll be able to move the old binary file and copy the new version of it, or there might be the situation when the other stuff used by your application needs to be replaced while your (still running) old version won't be able to understand them (e.g. a DB schema update). 2. You may (attempt to) move the old file (e.g. by renaming) and copy the new one. So yes, it is possible if you're lucky enough. 3. That insider means that I was building a few custom versions of InnoSetup making many internal changes :-)

Comment: Related question: [How to automatically update an application installed with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53073973/850848).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always write a script in your Inno Setup Update Installer that will check if app is running and close it automatically before update (`FindWindowByClassName` or `FindWindowByWindowName`). Or the better way is to create Mutex in you app and then to use [CheckForMutexes](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_checkformutexes) function.

Comment: For mutex is easier to just specify the [`AppMutex`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appmutex) directive.