# Is there a way to send software updates to clients without having a server?

Tags: python, exe, software-distribution, software-update

Is it possible to send Software Updates using some script built into the local software without having a server?

Currently I use Inno to turn my `.exe` files to `setup.exe`. I want to send out Software Updates to my users. Basically I want the software update to uninstall the old version of the software and install the fresh new version that I will be sending out.

Is AWS better or heroku?

Comment: Have code in your app that checks for updates from your server and applies them if they exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically update an application installed with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073973/how-to-automatically-update-an-application-installed-with-inno-setup)

Comment: Google has published their infrastructure for the purpose -- it's one of the many options available. That said, questions asking for help selecting between available tools (or libraries, or languages, etc) is off-topic here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can have a listener in you Software which looks at a certain URL(your server path) for new updates and if you have new update then update new software in that URL path. Then whenever on starting software it finds new update it can show popup to update software.

Comment: Questions that are too broad to answer adequately and in full should not be answered at all. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Center.